# How to get Number of rows in Jmeter using Json Path Extractor

Tags: jmeter

My Response is:

```
{
rows{
["2","xxx","yyyy"],
["3","xxx","yyyy"],
["4","xxx","yyyy"],
}
}
```

I am using `$.rows` to get all the rows. as well I am giving `$.rows[0].[1]` to get the value from 1st row and 1st value..

I am trying to get the total number of rows using `$.rows.size()` or `length`. It is not following exception. How to get the number of rows?

> Exception: Options AS_PATH_LIST and ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST are not allowed
>   when using path functions!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given the following JSON:

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
}
```

[image: JMeter Dummy Sampler]

If I add [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) as a child of the sample which returns the above JSON and configure it like:

- Reference Name: `arraySize`
- JSONPath Expression: `$..cars.length()`

[image: JMeter JSON PAth Extractor]

I am able to see the following variables in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

```
arraySize=[3]
arraySize_1=3
arraySize_matchNr=1
```

Which seems to be something you're looking for.

[image: JMeter Debug Sampler]

You can install JSON Path Extractor along with [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](http://How%20to%20Install%20the%20JMeter%20Plugins%20Manager)

[image: JMeter JSON Plugins Manager]

Comment: The same i have tried like $..rows.length(). This is not working.. Getting same error